# Trouble with PHP bitwise operators -Converting to Coldfusion

Tags: php, coldfusion, bit-manipulation

Trying to figure out what this does exactly and how to convert it to Coldfusion Tags:

`$result |= ord($built{$i}) ^ ord($signature{$i});`

I think I'm close:

`<cfset result = BitOr(ASC(built[i]),ASC(ARGUMENTS.signature[i])) />`

1. I know the `=` is wrong but I can't find in the PHP docs what exactly `|=` is doing.
2. `built` and `signature` are strings, and the php code uses `{$i}` and I don't understand why.
3. Not sure if `BitOr` is right or if I should use one of the other functions.

Anyone want to validate what I am doing and provide insight on where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<cfset result = BitOr(result, BitXor(ASC(built[i]),ASC(ARGUMENTS.signature[i]))) />
```

The `^` is the xor operator, not the or operator. Also, in PHP (and a bunch of other languages), `x |= y` means the same as `x = x | y` (and `x += y` means the same as `x = x + y` and so on).

Comment: Thanks. I'll plug this in today as I've moving this app from PHP to CF and see if I get the desired outcome.